# How to define lambda function in private?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, lambda, class-members

I want to hide details of the lambda function into `private` part of a class.

I tried to separate the lambda function part from `for_each()` function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Sol 
{
private:
    vector<int> vec = vector<int>{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int target = 10;
    auto lambdaFunc = [=](int& v) { v += target; };

public:
    void addConst() {
        for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), lambdaFunc);
    }

    void printVec() {
        for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int v) {cout << v << endl; });
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Sol sol;
    sol.addConst();
    sol.printVec();
    return 0;
}
```

If I don't separate `lambdaFunc` from the `for_each()` function, I got elements of vector printed out.
However, by separating `lambdaFunc`, I got error message:

```
error: non-static data member declared 'auto'
```

Changing `auto` to `static auto` didn't solve.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "If I don't separate lambdaFunc from the for_each() function, I got elements of vector printed out?"

Comment: Using a lambda as you did is simply abuse! If you want to define but not use it in the same moment, you should always write a standard (member) function which can be private. Defining an "auto lambda... type" did not help for anything.

Comment: @ArdaAytekin They mean that the code compiles and works as expected.

Comment: [Static auto lambda example](https://godbolt.org/z/JxfEu_) , one note: if you want to have static lambda, target must be also static.

Comment: Is `target` supposed to be constant?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) compiler, the best option is to provide a `private` member function as *@VittorioRomeo* shown in his answer(which is more straight forward IMO).

---

### [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) Solution!

Another way(s) is to provide the type for the lambda. You can

1. either use `std::function` with some type-erasure cost to define the
   type of the lambda.

   **([See Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yX5e30Zk2z9Anilz))**

   ```
   std::function<void(int&)> lambdaFunc = [=](int& v) { v += target; };
   ```
2. Or, if lambda can be changed to capture less one, that can be stored
   into a typed function pointer like follows. In which `target` will
   be passed as the second parameter of the lambda which made the lambda
   capture-less. But that need also change of `addConst()` function.

   **([See Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4nMduWlmLZGZfQOk))**

   ```
   class Sol 
   {
   private:
       std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
       //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ->  can use just braced-init-list
       int target{ 10 };
       void(*lambdaFunc)(int&, int) = [](int& v, int tar) { v += tar; };
       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ // fun-pointer type

   public:
       void addConst()
       {
           for (auto& element : vec) lambdaFunc(element, target);
       }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do this. If you really have a valid reason, you can use a `private` member function instead:

```
class Sol{
private:
    auto lambdaFunc() { return [=](int& v) { v += target; }; }

public:
    void addConst() {
        for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), lambdaFunc());
    }
};
```

Comment: I would call it something like `getLambdaFunc` since the higher-order nature of the function might not be immediately obvious otherwise...

Comment: You won't get away with that auto return type until c++17!

Comment: @GemTaylor: am I missing something? Why not C++14?

Comment: Maybe 14, but anyways not 11